# Unable to create facebook login in android application cannot find symbol method getAccessToken()

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am creating a facebook login for my android application. I am getting following below errors which i tried to solve but i can not because i am unable to find solution.

**1) Error:(46, 46) error: cannot find symbol method getAccessToken()**

**2) Error:(41, 55) error: incompatible types: > cannot be converted to FacebookCallback**

My **activity_main.xml** is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/activity_main"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="#5b9bd5"
     tools:context="com.example.ratingapp.ratingapp.MainActivity">


     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/info"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:textSize="18sp"
         />

     <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
         android:id="@+id/login_button"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         />


 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My **MainActivity.java** is:

```
  package com.example.ratingapp.ratingapp;

  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.ImageButton;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
  import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
  import com.facebook.FacebookException;
  import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
  import com.facebook.accountkit.LoginResult;
  import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
  import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

  import java.util.Arrays;
  import java.util.List;

  import static android.R.attr.data;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


      private TextView info;
      private LoginButton loginButton;
      private CallbackManager callbackManager;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
          loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
          List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email", "user_birthday", "public_profile");
          loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissionNeeds);
          loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                  info.setText(
                          "User ID: "
                                  + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                                  + "\n" +
                                  "Auth Token: "
                                  + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
                  );
              }

              @Override
              public void onCancel() {
                  info.setText("Login attempt canceled.");
              }

              @Override
              public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                  info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
              }
          });

      }
  }
```

Please help me solve these errors what i am doing wrong in this code.

Please alsoc check my **AndroidManifest.xml** incase i put a wrong facebook library.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.ratingapp.ratingapp">

     <application
         android:allowBackup="true"
         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:supportsRtl="true"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
         <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"  
         />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>
         <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
             android:configChanges=
             "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
             android:label="@string/app_name" />

         <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
             android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

     </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  /manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() 
{
 @Override
 public void onSuccess (final LoginResult loginResult)
 { 
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback()
      { 
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted (JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) 
                            {
                                try
                                {  
                                 String id = response.getJSONObject().getString("id");
     ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(passwordEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                
             if (connect()) 
             {   
                /*ENTER*/   
             }   
             else
             {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), textProblemConnecting(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             } 
        }
                                catch (JSONException e)
                                {
         e.printStackTrace();
        } 
                            }
                  });
                  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                  parameters.putString("YOUR FIELDS");
                  request.setParameters(parameters);
                  request.executeAsync();
              }
        
           @Override
           public void onCancel ()
           {
           
           }
        
           @Override
           public void onError (FacebookException e) 
           {
           
           }
       });
```

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "first_name, email, id, last_name, birthday, locale");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();